Can I Use the Stepper Motor Port on a Motor Driver to Control a DC Motor?
I have a HG7881 H-Bridge 4CH DC - 2CH Stepper Motor Driver Board. For my project, I need to control 5 motors: four 12V DC motors and one 3-6V water pump. I only need to turn the water pump on and off using a motor driver.
Can I connect the water pump (a DC motor) to one of the stepper motor ports on my driver board? If this isn’t possible, could anyone recommend a simple solution to control the 3-6V water pump or a any other compact motor driver.

Please provide information about the driver you have and the DC motor (Voltage/Power/datasheet). Do you need bidirectional control? Remove the shopping question aspect, it is not on topic here.

@Jens I modified the quotation according to the suggestion you gave me.

Do I understand this correctly? You want to connect 4 DC motors and the pump to only one HG7881 driver board? Or do you have two driver boards?

The HG7881 can deliver just 1 A continous current and 1.5 A peak current. Do you know the required startup current of the pump motor? I guess the pump needs more than this, so you probably must use two HG7881 ICs in parallel to drive the pump. If this is the case I can write an answer for the details.

@Jens Yes I want to connect 4 DC motors and the pump to only one HG7881 driver board if it's possible

@Jens and this are the pump Specifications:
Operating Voltage:- 3.3 - 6 VDC, Operating Current:- 130 - 220 mA,
Flow Rate:- 80 - 120 L/H, Maximum Lift:- 40 - 110 mm, Weigh:- 10g

The HG7881 driver IC can only set one of the two outputs to HIGH at a time, so you can enable only 4 motors at the same time with this module, even if they are driven unidirectional with one wire connected to GND.
It is possible to connect up to 8 unidirectional DC motors to this module, but only 4 of them can be active at any given time (except you run them with two alternating phases and below 50 % duty cycle).
If your project does not work with this restrictions or you want to keep it simple, I recommend to use a simple NFET to drive the pump using a PWM signal limited to 50% duty cycle. This will provide around 6 V for the pump motor if the supply of the circuit is 12 V.
Use a lower duty cycle for a lower pump voltage.
PWM frequencies between 100 and 2000 Hz are useful in this circuit.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
